# How to aggregate data in timeSequence?

Tags: r, aggregate, time-series

I have a problem and would really need your help? My data (let's name it "date") looks like this:

```
location       date  value
       1 2010-01-01    6.4
       1 2010-01-02    5.7
       .
       .  
       2 2010-01-01    0.8
       2 2010-01-02    2.5
       2 2010-01-03    5.5
```

I would like to aggregate data (value) on location and on 3 weeks period? I have already try to use package timeSeries but it is not working?

```
by1 <- timeSequence(from = "2009-12-30", to = "2010-12-29", by= "4 week")
by1
aggregate(date, by=list(by1, date$location), sum)
```

Comment: Hello MtS.  If Andrie's response solved your problem, you can/should 'accept' it, by clicking the checkmark next to it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using `seq.Date` to generate the break points, `cut` to bin your data, and `ddply` to summarize:

```
# Create sample data
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(
  location = rep(1:3, each=30),
  date = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), by="3 day", length.out=30), 3),
  value=rnorm(90)
)

# Create a sequence of dates in period of 3 weeks ot serve as cut points
dateCuts <- seq(from=min(dat$date), to=max(dat$date)+31, by="3 week")

# Use cut to separate dates into periods
dat$period <- cut(dat$date, breaks=dateCuts)

# Summarise data
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(location, period), summarize, value=mean(value))
```

The results:

```
   location     period       value
1         1 2010-01-01  0.04475859
2         1 2010-01-22  0.01062880
3         1 2010-02-12  0.62024902
4         1 2010-03-05 -0.31364304
5         1 2010-03-26 -0.03010425
6         2 2010-01-01 -0.08522653
7         2 2010-01-22  0.37708986
8         2 2010-02-12  0.12910449
9         2 2010-03-05  0.08597110
10        2 2010-03-26  0.21733251
11        3 2010-01-01  0.10295425
12        3 2010-01-22  0.46194453
13        3 2010-02-12 -0.35546029
14        3 2010-03-05  0.17216486
15        3 2010-03-26  0.31855880
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lubridate`, you can write this with a one-liner.

```
ddply(dat, .(location, ceiling(week(date)/3)), summarize, value = mean(value))
```

Comment: Very neat usage of `ceiling` and `week`, but are you sure this does the same thing?  `week` seems to return the week in the month - it doesn't bin into periods of n weeks.  Perhaps this is what the OP wanted (i.e. compare week 1 of Jan with week 1 of Feb), but my reading was compare weeks 1-3 with weeks 4-6 with weeks 7-9, etc.

Comment: @Andrie you are right. your solution takes care of the binning without this restriction.